# Elasticsearch - Count duplicated and unique values for a nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, count, match

[Elasticsearch - Count duplicated and unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359102/elasticsearch-count-duplicated-and-unique-values)

I need also same kind of count but that field is in nested properties as

```
[{
    "firstname": "john",
    "lastname": "doe",
    "addressList": [{
            "addressId": 39640,
            "txt": "sdf",
        }, {
            "addressId": 39641,
            "txt": "NEW",
        }, {
            "addressId": 39640,
            "txt": "sdf",
        }, {
            "addressId": 39641,
            "txt": "NEW"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "firstname": "jane",
    "lastname": "smith",
    "addressList": [{
            "addressId": 39644,
            "txt": "sdf",
        }, {
            "addressId": 39642,
            "txt": "NEW",
        }, {
            "addressId": 39644,
            "txt": "sdf",
        }, {
            "addressId": 39642,
            "txt": "NEW"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

what would be the query for addressId duplicate counts ? Need you help on this user:3838328

Comment: Could you share me your mapping details. It is done via `GET <your_index_name>/_mapping` Update the mapping information in your question and I will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks - @Kamal I got the solution as mentioned below.  URL mapping as _POST <your_index_name>/_search_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer for nested field duplicate counts as

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search

{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "prop_counts": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "addressList"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "duplicate_aggs": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "addressList.addressId",
                    "min_doc_count": 2, 
                    "size": 100                     <----- Note this
                }
            },
            "duplicate_bucketcount": {
                "stats_bucket": {
                    "buckets_path": "duplicate_aggs._count"
                }
            },
            "nonduplicate_aggs": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "addressList.addressId",
                    "size": 100                    <---- Note this
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "equal_one": {
                        "bucket_selector": {
                            "buckets_path": {
                                "count": "_count"
                            },
                            "script": "params.count == 1"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "nonduplicate_bucketcount": {
                "sum_bucket": {
                    "buckets_path": "nonduplicate_aggs._count"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

**Response as**

```
{
"took": 4,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
    "prop_counts": {
        "doc_count": 8,
        "duplicate_aggs": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{
                    "key": 39640,
                    "doc_count": 2
                }, {
                    "key": 39641,
                    "doc_count": 2
                }, {
                    "key": 39644,
                    "doc_count": 2
                }, {
                    "key": 39642,
                    "doc_count": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        "nonduplicate_aggs": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
        },
        "duplicate_bucketcount": {
            "count": 4,
            "min": 2,
            "max": 2,
            "avg": 2,
            "sum": 8
        },
        "nonduplicate_bucketcount": {
            "value": 0
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, accept your answer by clicking a grey arrow. Also if not yet done, could you please delete that post you've posted in my answer.

Comment: Hi Kamal - If there are more duplicate counts then it is not showing all in a single page. So what is "size":0 means ? If I want to delete the duplicate child list for the given example what should be the query ? need help on this if possible.

Comment: the size at the very top returns the original documents and if you only want aggregation query you should have it as 0. I've added size inside terms aggregation which should give you want you want. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Kamal - thanks for your answer. yes that helped me a lot.                                
Now I want to delete all these duplicate child elements and only to keep single child element. If possible help me on this.